# Subtracting out whole regions using occurrences (points)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, point-in-polygon

I have a bunch of occurrence points of animals scattered across a global map, and an eco-region map underneath it. I want to identify the eco-regions (i.e. Tundra) that does NOT contain any occurrence points. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions to count the points inside polygons founad at http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008599. Then simply select the features that have a count of 0.